# How can I get rid of these Git untracked files?

Tags: git

I was trying to create my first shopping cart in my Django project when I kept running into database issues and decided to get an older version of my code from my Git repository.
I downloaded the ZIP file from git and tested if the Git commands still function(git add, git commit, git push) as normal. When I tried to do'git add' then it added a whole lot of files that werent meant to be added.

I have tried doing git clean with all those parameters but it gives me an error that permission is denied. I am actually scared because these files look importnant and the fact that they require permission.

For future cases, if I would mess up again, could somebody tell me how can I just get an older version of my code from my GitHub repository back and continue to do (git add, git commit, git push).

[image: Example of what is going on]

Comment: Please never add text as an image. Always add the console output either as a code block or as a quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This big problem is that you've created or tried to create a `git` repo at the root of your Windows user directory. `Git` thinks that everything in there should be in your repo.

First thing I would do is show hidden folders and delete the `/.git/` folder and start over. Create a folder `c:\code\newFolder\` unzip your files there and create a new repo.

Once you have that, you can then move or ignore any files that don't need to be in `git`. Create a file `c:\code\newFolder\theRepo\.gitignore` and define which folder and file patterns to ignore.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore

It may be better for you to straight out clone the repo to a new folder, then checkout the older commit where you want to start working, create a new branch from that point and start working again. You can then eventually merge those changes to your main branch once everything's working correctly.

Comment: I deleted the .git folder which had all the untracked files. Cloned my repository to a new directory (in project folder) and everything is working now! Although I havent really touched .gitignore yet.. Thank you so much. You are a lifesaver.